# Segmentation fault Not happenign where it should

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I've brushing up on my C coding and going over some old exercises I did a couple of years back. I came accros a situation I am almost 100% sure it should give a segmentation fault, but instead the program runs smoothly and terminates correctly. Why is that happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int vals[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    vals[8]++; //This should not be ok!!?

    printf("Done");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no place where a segmentation fault should happen.

Comment: How is accessing a non-existing position of an array not a segmentation fault?

Comment: It's *undefined behavior*, whether it's a segmentation fault depends on other things. Oh, and there is no **vector** in your code, are you maybe thinking [tag:c++]?

Comment: @iharob Damn objects oriented languages messing with my C :p

Comment: @iharob: Old K&R used the term "vector" for arrays.

Comment: Oh, again K&R. The thing is, one of them is responsible for me being unable to quit programming, so I love him. And if he called them "*vectors*" (*he was a physicist and I am not surprised*) maybe you should to.

Comment: Undefined behavior is behavior which is not defined.

Comment: @iharob: K&R (not the ANSI-version) was the first and only C book I bought. After some first steps, I threw it into the corner and moved to Modula-2, mostly because of the extremely weak typing and other quirks. So I'm actually more a Wirth-man. I moved to C only with the first ANSI version which at least had a little reasonable behaviour and typing/checking. I still think some more hardware-oriented Modula-2 would be the better PL.

Comment: @Olaf I am not referring to the book, but to the creator of the [tag:c] language.

Comment: @iharob: I actually refered to the book. Actually there were two creators. But I think you are right why they choose "vector".

Comment: Indeed. Although physicists themselves tend to misuse the term *vector*. Mathematically, a *vector* is a one-dimensional tensor, that is it has to be invariant under tensor coordinate transfomations. I'd prefer the term *array* as they are just a bunch of numbers.

Comment: @Olaf [Brian Kernighan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan) denied having anything to do with the creation of C, so there's just one creator.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks, I seem to have missed something then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of `vals[8]` is *undefined*.

It's equivalent to `*(vals + 8)` which is *dereferencing* memory outside the bounds of the array.

A "segmentation fault" is one of many things that could happen. The compiler could also eat your cat.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering where did my cat go!

Comment: @iharob: surely you never use undefined constructs ;-)

Comment: If the first parameter of `strcat` is `&val[8]`, it will strangle your cat.

Comment: The OP question is a gross duplicate.